# Documentation file is not copied on tfs build server

Tags: c#, azure, tfs

I have an xml file that is created from code documentation. Xml file is in source control and it is in root of my project. This is .csproj:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Api.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <ItemGroup>
      <DocFile Include="bin\*\*\Api.xml" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(DocFile)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="wwwroot\**" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="wwwroot\**" />
    <None Remove="wwwroot\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="identityserver4_log.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Api.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="6.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Carable.Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.DocumentWithCode" Version="0.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Castle.Core" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="1.5.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="1.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="1.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Views\Default\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Api.Business\Api.Business.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

The file is not copied to wwwroot on my azure webapp. What do I have to set up?

Answer (score 0):

In the main section, ensure the documentation file gets generated:

```
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
```

You can try to specify the absolute path for the documentation file.

Reference below sample:

```
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <ItemGroup>
      <DocFile Include="bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\Api.xml" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(DocFile)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
  </Target>
```

More information please refer to this GitHub discussions: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/795

You can also try the solutions mentioned in this [copydocfile-example](https://github.com/spboyer/copydocfile-example).

Comment: net core throws an error for GenerateDocumentationFile in .csproj.

Comment: @AmelSalibasic What kind of the error? Could you please share the error messages here for further troubleshooting?

Comment: It says element not recognised

Comment: @AmelSalibasic Could you share the details steps to reproduce the issue? then we can do further troubleshoot accordingly.